# OOM exception in ImageAdapter

Tags: java, android

LogCat is giving me this error:

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 7485708 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 5MB until OOM"
--- decoder->decode returned false
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.holg.memory, PID: 2104
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 7485708 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
```

I'm adding 6 pictures to an array but when I add "pic_1" 6 times no error occurs. The are all ~ 200kb. The pictures are displayed in my GridView after OnClick. Sometimes I can click 3 times... sometimes only once. On my phone I can click more often.

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1,
        R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3,
        R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5,
        R.drawable.pic_6,
    };
```

My ImageAdapter Class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] pieces;
    private List<ImageView> imageViewsList;
    private int piece_up = -1;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        List<Integer> ipieces = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            ipieces.add(i);
            ipieces.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(ipieces);
        pieces = (Integer[]) ipieces.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        createImageViews();
    }

    private void createImageViews() {

        imageViewsList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        for(int position = 0; position < getCount(); position++) {
            ImageView imageView;

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);
            imageViewsList.add(imageView);

            installClick(position);
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 12; //mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imageViewsList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return pieces[position].longValue();
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public synchronized View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return (ImageView) imageViewsList.get(position);
    }

    public void installClick(int position) {
        // final int pos = position;
        final ImageAdapter self = this;
        Log.d("ImageAdapter", "click *" + Integer.toString(position));
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView)  imageViewsList.get(position);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = imageViewsList.indexOf((ImageView) v);
                Log.d("ImageAdapter", "click!" + Integer.toString(pos));
                show(pos);


                //UI update
                if (piece_up == -1 || piece_up == pos) {
                    // first click
                    piece_up = pos;
                } else {
                    // second click
                    if (pieces[pos] == pieces[piece_up]) {
                        // ok, it's equal
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "good!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //
                        // remove click handler
                        removeClick(pos);
                        removeClick(piece_up);

                    } else {
                        //try again;
                         int aux[] = {piece_up, pos};
                         SleepHide update = new SleepHide(mContext, self, aux);
                         Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                         mHandler.postDelayed(update, 1500);
                    }

                    piece_up = -1;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void removeClick(int position) {
        ImageView aux;
        aux = (ImageView) imageViewsList.get(position);
        aux.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

    public void hide(int position) {
        ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView) imageViewsList.get(position);
        //int piece = pieces[position];
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);
    }

    public void show(int position) {
        ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView) imageViewsList.get(position);
        int piece = pieces[position];
        img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[piece]);

    }
    //
    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pic_1,
            R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3,
            R.drawable.pic_4,
            R.drawable.pic_5,
            R.drawable.pic_6,
        };
}
class SleepHide implements Runnable {
    //private Context context;
    private int[] positions;
    private ImageAdapter adapter;

    public SleepHide(Context c, ImageAdapter b, int[] pos) {
        //context = c;
        adapter = b;
        positions = pos;

        Log.d("SleepHide", "click!");
        adapter.removeClick(pos[0]);
        adapter.removeClick(pos[1]);
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d("SleepHide", "run!");
        adapter.hide(positions[0]);
        adapter.hide(positions[1]);
        adapter.installClick(positions[0]);
        adapter.installClick(positions[1]);
    }

}
```

Comment: An OMM exception is cause by a meditation failure.  Perhaps you mean OOME? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line to application class declaration into manifest file to request a larger heap size.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

application class declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/title_image"
            android:largeHeap="true">
</application>
```

This will remove your OOM crashes completely!!

Comment: rebuild project and run again and it doesn't help you then try another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The app is going out of heap size.So you have to decode the image in such a way that it will fall under the heap size.Do this code in your adapter

You can change your show() method in adapter.

```
public void show(int position) {
ImageView img;
img = (ImageView) imageViewsList.get(position);
int piece = pieces[position];
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inSampleSize = 3;
    options.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            mThumbIds[piece],options);
img.setImageBitmap(icon);
```

}

Try once.

Comment: Ok, its working better now. At virtual device I can click maybe 15-20 times and on my phone much more. But the used Ram ist extremely high ( ~ 100 mb) I Think thats alot for this little app. But okay... poorly written by me .